# How Can I group by a certain field value and get unique records

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I have a table called as department and i would show a report based on attendance and i need to merge all the employers in a department to their respective department. Eg : department 1=> 1,2,3 and Department2 =>4,5,6 .i tried group by but it makes all the employers having a certain department merged  i.e depatment1 only contains 3 when i used groupby. Is there function in php to get unique datas when fetching

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 15
            [department_name] => R&D
            [name] => SUBRAMANIAN
            [code] => 101
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => RAVI
            [code] => 103
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => AMULRAJAN.A
            [code] => 104
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => KANAKARAJ.R
            [code] => 105
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => ELAYARAJA
            [code] => 106
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => SIVAKUMAR.T
            [code] => 108
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => PALANISAMY.R
            [code] => 110
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => SAKKIYAN.K
            [code] => 112
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => Jeyaprakash
            [code] => 113
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )
```

I need department ->Manufacturing contains RAVI,AMULRAJAN.A,KANAKARAJ.R etc not merge it  when use groupby

This is my mysql query :

```
SELECT `tbl_employee_basicdetails`.`employee_id`, `tbl_employee_basicdetails`.`employee_name`, `tbl_employee_basicdetails`.`employee_code`,  `tbl_employee_officedetails`.`department` FROM `tbl_employee_basicdetails` JOIN `tbl_employee_officedetails` ON `tbl_employee_officedetails`.`employee_id`=`tbl_employee_basicdetails`.`employee_id` WHERE `tbl_employee_basicdetails`.`employee_act` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an array of the sql result, one solution in php would be to "transform"  the result array into an array with `department_name` as key and employee details as the elements. Something like this should work:

```
$departments=[];
foreach ($results as $emp) {

    $departments[$emp['department_name']][] = $emp;
}
```

Comment: let me try it and say to you

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array gets error

Comment: This assumes `$results` is an _array_ of the sql query results, as with [`msyqli_fetch_array`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).